# android - call method in view from activity

Tags: java, android

I am working on a 2d game and I'm trying to make the view where I draw and update everything tell the activity that contains it that the game ended and display a pop-up on the screen. The problem is that I don't know how to access the method in the activity from the view because they work on different threads.

The code looks more or less like this and I want to access the method displayFrame() from the view class. The method in the real code does more operations with other textViews etc. that only the activity has access to.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private MyView myView;
    RelativeLayout finalFrame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myView = new MyView(this.getApplicationContext());
        this.setContentView(myView);

        finalFrame = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.framefinal);
    }

    private void displayFrame(){
        this.finalFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public class MyView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private MyThread myThread;
    private boolean finished = false;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        this.myThread = new MyThread(getHolder(), this);

        this.myThread.setRunning(true);
    }

    public void update() {
        this.finished = someMethod();
        if(this.finished){
            MainActivity.displayFrame();
        }
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        //draw something
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}

public class MyThread extends Thread{
    private MyView myView;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private boolean running = false;
    private static Canvas canvas;

    public MyThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MyView myView){
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.myView = myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(running){
            canvas = null;

            try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    this.myView.update();
                    this.myView.draw(canvas);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            finally{
                if(canvas!=null)
                {
                    try {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running){
        this.running = running;
    }
}
```

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {  is is like that or just pasting problem

Comment: it's not...sorry :P edited it (just a paste problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to define a listener interface in your view and make the activity implement it. Then you can notify the activity that your game has ended and execute the appropriate logic.

```
public class MyView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

     // your other fields
     private GameListener mGameListener;

     public void setGameListener(GameListener gameListener) {
         mGameListener = gameListener;
     }

     public void update() {
         // your logic
         if (mGameListener != null) {
             // calling onGameEnd on the main thread
             post(new Runnable() {

                 public void run() {
                     mGameListener.onGameEnd();
                 }

             });
         }
     }

     // rest of your class as it is

     public interface GameListener {

         void onGameEnded();

     }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GameListener {

    // the rest of your class

    public void onGameEnded() {
        // call the method you need
    } 
}
```

Comment: update: the layout is constructed but not drawn....I can click the buttons on the view but I cannot graphically see it or anything that it contains

Comment: Which layout is not drawn exactly?

Comment: finalFrame...the thing is that the layout exists since I can click on it's buttons after setting it on visible but I cannot graphically see it

Comment: OK, since you are calling `update()` from the update thread, turns out that you are trying to update the layout from a worker thread, and this should only by done by the main thread. I will update my answer to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private MyThread myThread;
private boolean finished = false;
private Context context;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context=context;

    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    this.myThread = new MyThread(getHolder(), this);

    this.myThread.setRunning(true);
}

runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){
    update();
}
});

    public void update() {
    this.finished = someMethod();
    if(this.finished){
        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
        mainActivity.displayFrame();
    }
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    //draw something
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
}
```

Can you try this

Comment: this doesn't work because I cannot cast the context to MainActivity

Comment: what you mean you can not cast , what prevents you to do so ?

Comment: it seems like the context changed and I receive an error saying that it cannot be cast

Comment: well not really haha...this exception jumps in the thread and it's not displaying the layout graphically: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: i believe you have got it from @Danail Alexiev

Comment: the answer i gave you is for just that method to call , but if you have huge work to do , better is inter communication design pattern i.e the interface way ,and in above as you are getting the context just store it in Myview class and then use it ..

Comment: what is the error you are getting when typecasting the context ?

Comment: I thought it worked until I paused a chronometer that was in the activity (the original code has more elements) and it didn't show anymore because the exception in the thread was jumping (if I comment the pausing, the exception still jumps)

Comment: private void displayFrame(){
        this.finalFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } this is the code you want call from MyView?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to activities.MainActivity

Comment: displayFrame(){ this.finalFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } is the main thing that I want to do in this method but I do have more operations with textViews inside and a chronometer widget.

Comment: whatever you want to update from a thread  you have to play around runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){
   //Update UI thread
}